# The part of one vector that is perpendicular to another, in 3D

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I've been wrangling this question for a good 2 hours, yet according to this past paper, it should only be worth 3 minutes work (obviously, to one who has properly practiced manipulating 3D vectors at this level).

> Two vectors, $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$, lie in 3D space. Show by explicit construction that the part of $\mathbf a$ that is perpendicular to $\mathbf b$ can be represented by:
>   $$\mathbf{a}_{perp} = \mathbf a - \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b \frac{\mathbf b}{\mathbf b \cdot \mathbf b}$$

My immediate thought was that $\mathbf a_{perp}$ would be in the same direction as $(\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) \times \mathbf b$, since it is perpendicular to both the normal of the plane containing $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$, and the vector $\mathbf b$ itself. This expression can be written as
$$(\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b) \mathbf b - (\mathbf b \cdot \mathbf b) \mathbf a\,.$$
The magnitude should be equal to $|\mathbf a|\sin\theta$ (where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors), or equivalently,
$$|\mathbf a_{perp}| = \frac{|\mathbf a \times \mathbf b|}{|\mathbf b|}$$
So now I've got the disastrous result of
$$\mathbf a_{perp} = \frac{(\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b) \mathbf b - (\mathbf b \cdot \mathbf b) \mathbf a}{|(\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b) \mathbf b - (\mathbf b \cdot \mathbf b) \mathbf a|}\,\frac{|\mathbf a \times \mathbf b|}{|\mathbf b|}$$
which I just can't seem to wrangle into the lovely form given in the question! Have I taken a wrong turn somewhere? Is there a much nicer way of doing this?

Thanks in advance! :)

P. S. I'm a first-year physics major, so apologies if this question turns out horribly easy.

P. P. S. I am now aware this is a well-known theorem for any inner product space. Nothing I've found has helped me prove it, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to extract the answer from this picture.

[image]

Comment: I can already see it. D a m n. So simple after all. Cheers!

Comment: I was going to write down the proof and I remembered this picture is out there. I'm glad you got it.